# Extending Vue3 components

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, webstorm

I would like to create a wrapper component (let's call it `B.vue`) around another component (`A.vue`).

I would like `B.vue` to have all the slots, props, `v-model` bindings, events etc. that `A.vue` has. (along with intellisense auto completions in WebStorm)

The exposed values of `A.vue` should also be available directly on `B.vue`.

---

Conveniently, Vue now allows to use typescript interfaces in `defineProps<Interface>()`, so inheriting the prop types is solved by this. However, I did have some issues with slots & custom `v-model` bindings.

For slots, I used this code:

```js
<template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" #[name]="slotData">
    <slot :name="name" v-bind="slotData" />
</template>
```

Which works, but WebStorm shows a warning about an unknown slot when I use the slot of `A.vue` in `B.vue`.

I then used the following bindings for attributes and props: `v-bind="$attrs" v-bind.prop="$props"`.
Which also works, but WebStorm doesn't provide any code hints when assigning custom `v-model`s etc.

This is what the whole file of `B.vue` looks like:

```js
<template>
    <A v-bind="$attrs" v-bind.prop="$props">
        <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" #[name]="slotData">
            <slot :name="name" v-bind="slotData" />
        </template>
    </A>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

defineProps<AProps>()

</script>
```

And let's say that this is `A.vue`:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <slot />

        <button @click="$emit('customEvent')">
            Emits a custom event
        </button>

        <div>
            <slot name="label" :data="someData" />
            <input v-model="customModel" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

const someData = ref<string>('data')

const customModel = defineModel<string>('something')

const emit = defineEmits<{
    customEvent: [],
}>()

</script>
```

Is there any way to get the auto-completions to show up?
Are there any better ways of creating wrappers for components?
*(I want to create versions of a component which will have default html content in some slots. This default content will be different for each version of the same component, though, so providing it in the `<slot>` tag is not a viable option for me as that would only allow me to specify one default value.)*

Comment: This seems rather a IDE problem than a Vue problem.. I would advise you to change your tags if you want an answer. IMO the majority of the 'Vue programmers' don't even care the slightest about auto completion in their editor. But maybe some Webstorm IDE users had/have the same problem as you.

Comment: If the question is specific to Webstorm, it doesn't make sense to ask it in general. Consider addressing Jetbrains support, which is also active on SO. As for extendable comps, not using script setup may be more universal and less quirky, so `props: {...CompA.props}` could be used when extending

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I updated the tags.

Comment: I also use Webstorm and yes, I also encountered the same problem - it just seems like a Vue3 SFC - file limitation for now. But as with Vue2 & Typescript I guess it will be updated. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2023/11/webstorm-2023-3-eap-3/#improvements_for_vue & newer - Seems like there is active work on it.

Comment: Regarding your default Slots - you could still use the <component> Tag to switch between variable default slot-contents. Would that be an option?

Comment: Sadly, using <component> for the default content isn’t very practical for my use case. I have a parent Nuxt layer with default components (let’s use a checkbox as an example) which I’m extending in child layers and I would like the DX to be as seamless as possible - so defining the checkbox content every time I use it isn’t a good solution for me. Though, it is a clever idea which I didn’t think of! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try to declare the slots in your B.vue wrapper.

```
<template>
    <A v-bind="$attrs" v-bind.prop="$props">
        <slot v-if="$slots.default" :name="undefined" />

        <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" #[name]="slotData">
            <slot :name="name" v-bind="slotData" />
        </template>
    </A>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import A, { AProps } from './A.vue';

defineProps<AProps>();

defineSlots({
    // Explicitly declare slots if needed
    default: () => [],
    label: (data: any) => [h('span', data)],
});

</script>
```

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply. I actually used the typescript version of `defineSlots` and it does work! Thank you! Seems like the only thing I cannot get autocompletions for at the moment is cusotm v-model bindings and events.
However, in `B.vue`, there are 3 functions [`defineProps<Props>()`, `defineSlots<Slots>()`, `defineEmits<Emits>()`] + the v-for for slots now and it's getting a little cluttered. I am planning to extend components a lot in this way and this brings a lot of boilerplate. Isn't there an easier way? 

Comment: It also occurred to me that if I wanted to call an exposed method of `A.vue`, I'd have to access it through `B.vue` like this: `bRef.$refs.aRef.exposedMethod()`  
Ideally, I would prefer a solution that behaves as if I copied A.vue and only altered the HTML content in a few slots.